# empty page after tablix (Reporting services 2008)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have created a report which contains a tablix. I observed that when the 
tablix contains a certain amount of rows, a blank page is added after the page with the tablix with only the header and footer of my report.
This happens both in design and print view, even if the tablix has only about 10 rows and there is a lot of space till the end of the report body (which has a height of 27cm).

I have not added any kind of page break. Has somebody perhaps had this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. set the **ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace** property for the tablix to true.
   If that doesn't work.
2. check that the (Body Height + Header height + Footer Height) = report page size height 
       (body width = header width = footer width = report page size width)

Comment: Great, perfect. The property is in the report though ;)

Comment: Hours, and hours.  This one setting (ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace) did it.  I would upvote 20 times if I could.  Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is different between different versions but the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace was on my report not on my tablix. Switch to Document Outline Mode.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a good idea to set the width of the body a little less than page width - (left + right margin). 
In my last report, page width was 21 cm with both left and right margin = 0.5 cm. With a body width of 20 cm **and** ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace=true, I still got a second page in print layout, but not with a body width of 19.9 cm.